# Copy files from one path to another path in TFVC repository using Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to copy files from one folder path to another folder path in the TFVC repository using Powershell script in CI as mentioned below.

```
Get-Item -path $/SCSM/CMC/1.1.0.0/Dev/1.1.1.0/TSC/ServiceRuleScript - Destination $/SCSM/CCB/1.0.0.0/Dev/1.0.1.0/TSC/RulesEngine
```

When trying the above script getting the below error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\privateagent\_work\66\s\$/SCSM/CMC/1.1.0.0/Dev/1.1.1.0/TSC/ServiceRuleScript
```

We tried with the copy file task in CI, it is getting executed but we are unable to see the file in the destination folder path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/manvZ.png)

Please help me out with this task.

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation and write the code here or github, instead of people have to watch the youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that your Source Folder is wrong.**
Use this [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services):

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\{your folder want to be copied}
```

[image]

**It works on my side:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to call file from one path "Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts
and we are using the copy task to call file in another path "CCM/1.0.0.0/1.1.0.0/Dev/1.1.1.0". Both are different paths. When we are trying to call the file using copy file task getting the below error.

##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: C:\privateagent_work\66\s\Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts

But the file which we are trying to call is in the below path: "C:\privateagent_work\79\s\Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts

We have mentioned the below path in our copy task
Source folder in copy task - $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts

The problem here in the copy task is - The copy file task should call file from "C:\privateagent_work\79\s\Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts" but it is trying to call the file from "C:\privateagent_work\66\s\Masters\DbProject\V1.0.0.1\PowershellScripts

Please share your inputs.